# Grails - %252F in the url

Tags: grails

I am using spring security plugin for login in application. The spring security has default `auth.gsp` page for login. I have created my own `auth.gsp` page to add additional thing

`auth.gsp`

```
<g:form action='${postUrl.encodeAsURL()}' method='POST' id='loginForm'  autocomplete='off' class="login-form">
            <g:textField class="field" name="username" value="${params.userName}"/>
            <g:passwordField class="field" name="password"/>
            <button>login</button>
            <p class="message"><a href="elb/index">Forgot Password?</a></p>
            <p class="message"><a id="next" name="next" href="#">Have Invitation Code?</a></p>
        </g:form>
```

The problem is that `${postUrl}` contains `%252F` in the url. Here is the complete url: `http://localhost:8080/login/%252Flogin%252Fauthenticate/loginForm`. I have tried every possible answer given on stackoverflow but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
<g:form url='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm'  autocomplete='off' class="login-form">
        <g:textField class="field" name="username" value="${params.userName}"/>
        <g:passwordField class="field" name="password"/>
        <button>login</button>
        <p class="message"><a href="elb/index">Forgot Password?</a></p>
        <p class="message"><a id="next" name="next" href="#">Have Invitation Code?</a></p>
    </g:form>
```

When setting complete urls, you use 'url' attribute. If you use "action", then you must set a action name.

Also don't use encodeAsURL(). encodeAsURL means, you want to escape special characters like '/','?' which are replaced with '%..' entities.

Comment: The `encodeAsUrl()` should not be used in this case. It should just be `${postUrl}` instead.

Comment: Yes @JoshuaMoore you are right. I was editing but you are fast.